# how to change <host:port> to domain in swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

[image]

in the picture swagger request use host and port,so browser console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://115.159.22.159:9001/bp/api/v1/user/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://twogoods.cc' is therefore not allowed access.`
how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
public Docket categoryApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host("twogoods.cc")
            .groupName("bookplatform-api")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .paths(apiPaths())
            .build()
            .directModelSubstitute(java.sql.Timestamp.class, java.sql.Date.class)
            .enableUrlTemplating(false);
}
```

`host()` method!!!

Comment: Now I'm aware of the host() method can change the "try it out" URL, but I still got one more question: how can i get the host automatically (like HttpServletRequest.getServerName() instead of type it in manually?  And I am not looking forward to a specific host from configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`host(..)`](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#host(java.lang.String)) and [`protocols(..)`](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#protocols(java.util.Set)) methods, to override the default values.

#### e.g.

```java
@Bean
public Docket customImplementation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .protocols(Collections.singleton("https"))
        .host("twogoods.cc")
        .select()
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Any idea if it can be done dynamically, such as choose the host name depending on the actual domain name, so that no changes have to be done when deployed to various env?

Comment: @Joey587 - Not sure, but you probably have three options (in order of feasibility, *not tested): 
a) Externally configure the domain name (at startup) using an environment variable.
b) Lazy initialise the `Docket` bean, and use the first [`Host`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) header received to configure the bean
c) Get the external IP address and do a reverse lookup (here be dragons)