# Address IP instead of host name as generated server URL

Tags: swagger

I have Swagger on my project, I opening it by server name (not by IP) and I see address IP as generated server URL:

[image]

If I want to call some method from Swagger I get:

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

I think that error shows because of IP as server name, instead of host name.

Do you know how to put host name instead of IP address in generated server URL? Maybe after that I will be able to send request without CORS problem.

[how to change <host:port> to domain in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098775/how-to-change-hostport-to-domain-in-swagger)
here is similar question, but I have many enviroments, and I cannot just put 'www.myurl.com' in host() parameter

Comment: The error is about the _scheme_, not whether or not the hostname is an IP. What's led you to zero in on the IP as a problem? Did you look at the actual requests it's making?

Comment: request making by swagger: GET http://10.27.2.69:8080/nawa-services/api/institution/doctoral-schools/all with CORS error in response. If I put this address in new tab of browser, I got proper response, only in swagger there's a problem, due to CORS

Comment: Well that, unlike what's shown in your screenshot, indeed does not have a scheme.

Comment: browser probably defaults to https too.